# Changing Carto basemap according to timestamp?

Tags: carto, time, basemap, mapping, animation

I'm making an animated "time-map" of the avaibility of renting bikes during a day (on Carto).

Can I change the basemap so when it's day time the basemap is light and when it's night time the basemap is dark?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot change your BUILDER basemap that way. To fulfill that requirement you need to create a [CartoDB.js](https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/carto-js/) ad-hoc application where you play with Torque events to switch basemaps.

This [code example](http://bl.ocks.org/ernesmb/4939b3751d3be0cdd64b) does something totally different but it makes use of the `change:time` event trigger.